# range view as data member

Tags: c++, boost-graph, range-v3

I'm trying out the new range-v3 library (0.5.0, clang-7.1)

I'm traversing through a graph (bfs). Each node in the graph contains some vector data (`std::vector<double>`). While traversing through the graph, I'm trying to create a `concat_view` (which is concatenation of all the vectors).

I'm trying to store this `concat_view` as a member variable of the graph traversal class. (`default_bfs_visitor` from boost graph library, to be precise). So, upfront, I will not know how many vectors I'm going to encounter. I'm doing something like this.

```
struct bfs_visitor 
{
private:
    ranges::v3::any_view<double> mView;
public:
    template<class Graph>
    void finish_vertex (vertex_descriptor v, const Graph& g) 
    {
        auto node = g[v];
        std::vector<double>& data = dataForNode(node);
        mView = ranges::v3::concat(mView, data);
    }
};
```

After I'm done visiting the graph, I process the view to extract the required information.

As the type of `mView` changes with each `concat` operation, I'm unable to explicitly specify the type of `mView` in the declaration.

[This link](https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmOBLl5YGbuq8Dbi3nlDy2lKA4gNriMdRA) says there's performance hit for `any_view`. Is `any_view` the only option?

Comment: your link does not work

Comment: can you make bfs_visitor templated on the view and make finish_vertex return the new bfs_visitor as the result of the concat?

Comment: @BobBills That can't work if the number of `finish_vertex` calls is arbitrary and only known at runtime.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't a view that flattens a range of ranges. If there were, you would just accumulate your `data`s and then flatten.

Comment: `view::join` flattens a range of ranges.

Comment: The link in the question is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nail the issue on the head:

- the return type of `ranges::v3::concat` is different so you need type-erasure (any_view e.g.).
- type erased lazy composed ranges are a bad idea performance-wise

In your situation I would not hesitate to replace view with a *reified* container:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7df9411111052241)</kbd>**

```
struct bfs_visitor 
{
private:
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double> > mView;
public:
    template<class Graph>
    void finish_vertex (vertex_descriptor v, const Graph& g) 
    {
        auto& node = g[v];
        ranges::v3::push_back(mView, dataForNode(node));
    }
};
```

> **NOTE IMPORTANT**
>
> Note that I made `auto& node` a reference, instead of taking a copy. Concatenating views of temporary copies is a [bad idea (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
>
> If you happen to know that `dataForNode(node)` does NOT return a reference to member data from `node`, then this is not a real issue and you can disregard this comment.
>
> **PHYSIC MODE ENGAGED:**
>
> If your issue was that `g` is `Graph const&` and the view is not readonly, 
>   either
>
> - make `mView` an `any_view<double const>`
> - store a non-const pointer to your graph in the visitor and use that instead of the `g` argument

In fact, if you don't need them to be references at all (this is the key property of a view):

```
struct bfs_visitor 
{
private:
    std::vector<double> mCollectedData;
public:
    template<class Graph>
    void finish_vertex (vertex_descriptor v, const Graph& g) {
        ranges::v3::push_back(mCollectedData, dataForNode(g[v]));
    }
};
```

> **Note** Another slightly weird thing is that your visitor templates the `Graph` argument type, but not the `vertex_descriptor`. Again, it's hard to know whether it's actually wrong without seeing the rest of the code, but it's certainly a-typical.
>
> The vertex descriptor type is characteristic of the Graph type, so consider 
>    - writing `typename Graph::vertex_descriptor` or `typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor`
>    - making the operator() non-template

Comment: It certainly answered my question. The `vertex_descriptor` is indeed `typename Graph::vertex_descriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* store an `any_view<double>`, as you wrote in your original question.

The problem was that you were trying to do a `| ranges::view::concat(...)` operation multiple times at runtime.  Each time a range is concat-ed, it creates a different type.

Instead, you can use `ranges::view::join` to "flatten" the sequence of vectors of doubles, into a range of doubles.  See this question, which is on point:  [range v3 flattening a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577873/range-v3-flattening-a-sequence)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

struct graph 
{
    using node_data = std::vector<double>;
private:
    std::set<node_data> m_nodes;
    ranges::v3::any_view<double> m_view;  // Must be updated whenever a node is added/updated.

    void update_view() 
    {
        m_view = m_nodes | ranges::view::join;
    }
public:
    template<typename Container>
    graph(const Container& c) 
        : m_nodes{std::begin(c), std::end(c)}
    {
        update_view();
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return m_nodes.size(); }
    const ranges::v3::any_view<double>& data_view() const { return m_view; }
};
```

I tried to create an alias for the exact type of the `join` iterator, instead of using `any_view`, but I couldn't get it to work.  It should be possible with `decltype`.

This would be used as follows ([Wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ul51aG4vls3NEIxd)):

```
int main()
{
    using node_data = graph::node_data;
    auto data = {node_data{0.}, node_data{1.1, 2.2}, node_data{3.3, 4.4, 5.5}, node_data{6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9}};

    graph g{data};
    std::cout << "Graph size (nodes): " << g.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Combined data:      ";
    auto r = g.data_view();
    for (double val : r)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Graph size (nodes): 4
Combined data:      0 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9
```