# Understanding composition of lazy range-based functions

Tags: c++, boost, lazy-evaluation, undefined-behavior, boost-adaptors

### TL;DR

What's wrong with the last commented block of lines below?

```cpp
// headers and definitions are in the down the question
int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{10,20,30};

    using type_of_temp = std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>,int>>;

    // seems to work, I think it does work
    auto temp = copy_range<type_of_temp>(v | indexed(0)
                                           | transformed(complex_keep_index));
    auto w = temp | transformed(distribute);
    print(w);

    // shows undefined behavior
    //auto z = v | indexed(0)
    //           | transformed(complex_keep_index)
    //           | transformed(distribute);
    //print(z);
}
```

Or, in other words, what makes piping `v | indexed(0)` into `transformed(complex_keep_index)` well defined, but piping `v | indexed(0) | transformed(complex_keep_index)` into `transformed(distribute)` undefined behavior?

### Extended version

I have a container of things,

```cpp
std::vector<int> v{10,20,30};
```

and I have a function which generates another container from *each* of those things,

```cpp
// this is in general a computation of type
//      T -> std::vector<U>
constexpr auto complex_comput = [](auto const& x){
    return std::vector{x,x+1,x+2}; // in general the number of elements changes
};
```

so if I was to apply the `complex_comput` to `v`, I'd get,

```cpp
{{10, 11, 12}, {20, 21, 22}, {30, 31, 32}}
```

and if I was to also concatenate the results, I'd finally get this:

```cpp
{10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32}
```

However, I want to keep track of the index where each number came from, in a way that the result would encode something like this:

```
0 10
0 11
0 12
1 20
1 21
1 22
2 30
2 31
2 32
```

To accomplish this, I (eventually) came up with this solution, where I attempted to make use of ranges from Boost. Specifically I do the following:

1. use `boost::adaptors::indexed` to attach the index to each element of `v`
2. transform each resulting "pair" in a `std::pair` storing the `index` and result of the application of `complex_comput` to the `value`,
3. and finally transforming each `std::pair<st::vector<int>,int>` in a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`.

However, I had to give up on the range between 2 and 3, using a helper "true" `std::vector` in between the two transformations.

```cpp
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indexed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using boost::adaptors::indexed;
using boost::adaptors::transformed;
using boost::copy_range;

constexpr auto complex_comput = [](auto const& x){
// this is in general a computation of type
//      T -> std::vector<U>
    return std::vector{x,x+1,x+2};
};
constexpr auto complex_keep_index = [](auto const& x){
    return std::make_pair(complex_comput(x.value()), x.index());
};
constexpr auto distribute = [](auto const& pair){
    return pair.first | transformed([n = pair.second](auto x){
        return std::make_pair(x, n);
    });
};

template<typename T>
void print(T const& w) {
    for (auto const& elem : w) {
        for (auto i : elem) {
            std::cout << i.second << ':' << i.first << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{10,20,30};

    using type_of_temp = std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>,int>>;

    auto temp = copy_range<type_of_temp>(v | indexed(0)
                                           | transformed(complex_keep_index));
    auto w = temp | transformed(distribute);
    print(w);

    //auto z = v | indexed(0)
    //           | transformed(complex_keep_index)
    //           | transformed(distribute);
    //print(z);
}
```

Indeed, decommenting the lines defining and using `z` gives you a code that compiles but generates rubbish results, i.e. undefined behavior. Note that applying `copy_range<type_of_temp>` to the first, working, range is necessary, otherwise the resulting code is essetially the same as the one on the right of `auto z =`.

Why do I have to do so? What are the details that makes the oneliner not work?

I partly understand the reason, and I'll list my understanding/thoughts in the following, but I'm asking this question to get a thorough explanation of all the details of this.

- I understand that the undefined behavior I observe stems from `z` being a range whose defining a view on some temporary which has been destroyed;
- given the working version of the code, it is apparent that temporary is `v | indexed(0) | transformed(complex_keep_index)`;
- however, isn't `v | indexed(0)` itself a temporary that is fed to `transformed(complex_keep_index)`?
- Probably one important detail is that the expression `v | indexed(0)` is no more than a lazy range, which evaluates nothing, but just sets things up such that when one iterates on the range the computations is done; after all I can easily do `v | indexed(0) | indexed(0) | indexed(0)`, which is well defined;
- and also the whole `v | indexed(0) | transformed(complex_keep_index)` is well defined, otherwise the code above using `w` would probably misbehave (I know that UB doesn't mean that the result has to show something is wrong, and things could just look ok on this hardware, in this moment, and break tomorrow).
- So there's something inherently wrong is passing an rvalue to `transformed(distribute)`;
- but what's wrong in doing so lies in `distribute`, not in `transformed`, because for instance changing `distribute` to `[](auto x){ return x; }` seems to be well defined.
- So what's wrong with `distribute`? Here's the code

```cpp
constexpr auto distribute = [](auto const& pair){
    return pair.first | transformed([n = pair.second](auto x){
        return std::make_pair(x, n);
    });
};
```

- What's the problem with it? The returned range (output of this `transformed`) will hold some iterators/pointers/references to `pair.first` which is part of goes out of scope when `distribute` returns, but `pair` is a reference to something in the caller, which keeps living, right?
- However I know that even though a `const` reference (e.g. `pair`) can keep a temporary (e.g. the elements of `v | indexed(0) | transformed(complex_keep_index)`) alive, that doesn't mean that the temporary stays alive when that reference goes out of scope just because it is in turn referenced by something else (references/pointers/iterators in the output of `transformed([n = …](…){ … })`) which doesn't go out of scope.

I think/hope that probably the answer is already in what I've written above, however I need some help to streamline all of that so that I can understand it once and for all.

Comment: The vectors returned by `complex_comput` or `complex_keep_index` are temporaries, and you keep going with the transform chain after their lifetime ends. Not even rangev3 has a nice solution here, I think (they require a `viewable_range` (lvalue or view of one))

Comment: @sehe please, feel free to post an answer, it you can add details to your comment. For instance, what about the third bullet point in the list? Is it about xvalues vs prvalues?

Comment: I don't suppose it is. I have spent ~40 mins trying to come up with an alternative spelling that doesn't reify intermediates. I have failed (with Rangev3) as well. That's the part I like to focus on. (This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577873/range-v3-flattening-a-sequence) was pretty helpful along my way.) PS rangev3 actually spits out errors instead of compiling into UB here, so that's good)

Comment: @sehe if it fails with any rvalue, both xvalues and prvalues, that means that ` v | indexed(0) | transformed(complex_keep_index);` works because `v | indexed(0)` is an lvalue. But is it?

Comment: Nah. That's simply a lazy range that _hasn't yet produced the vectors_ (it will do so on iteration). That means that the temporary vectors are not a problem yet.